# Why are the download numbers for @azure/identity, @azure/msal-node, auth0, and passport currently declining? What is replacing those?

Tags: azure, passport.js, auth0, azure-ad-msal

All of those packages have a declining number of downloads lately? Is there a new way to authorize to Azure AD? Or is it related to JavaScript? What is the currently preferred way to authorize and authenticate with OAuth2.0 against Azure?

[image]

[Source of graph](https://npmtrends.com/@auth0-vs-@azure/identity-vs-@azure/msal-node-vs-auth0-vs-passport)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the "Downloads in past:" UI input field to "All time", you will see that there are these dramatic drops every year at around the same time of year. It's the holiday season. Lots of people are on work holiday or off school or just taking a break from working on personal projects. That's why there are fewer package downloads. You'll also see that the overall trend for the packages you listed is upward growth. You'll also see similar patterns for pretty much *every* package on the main NPM registry.

I.e. the data does not indicate that their usage is on an overall decline (it's the opposite). I'm pretty sure your misinterpretation of the data invalidates your other questions.